# Making Ubuntu host allocate same DHCP IP address to same guest VM all the time

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 and I have  Oracle VM VirtualBox  7.0.4 on it. I have created several VMs (all Linux VMs) on VirtualBox. I need DHCP  to allocate same IP address to a particular VM. I installed the `isc-dhcp-server` package and made the changes to `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` but it allocates another IP address (in the same subnet) every time.

I made these changes to  `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file.  `vmr120` is the name of  Linux VM running on VirtualBox:

```
host vmr120 {
  hardware ethernet 08:00:27:be:df:f7;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.22;
}
```

And I restarted the DHCP server:

```
sudo systemctl  restart isc-dhcp-server.service
```

But when I start the VM  `vmr120`  I see the IP address is again  `192.168.1.7`

Not sure what other changes I need to make OR what is the mistake I am making in specifying the `dhcpd.conf` entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pool declaration for a block of addresses reserved for regular DHCP allocation, then your MAC based declarations need to appear first in your `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. Otherwise if a MAC based client already has an entry from the pool from the past, expired or not, it will get that old IP address again.

Example from my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file:

```
...
host serv-bb {
  hardware ethernet 52:54:00:27:1b:2e;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.215;
}

host serv-xx {
  hardware ethernet 52:54:00:60:ea:0e;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.216;
}

host serv-ff {
  hardware ethernet 52:54:00:27:1b:4e;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.217;
}

# The Basic DHCP allocated addresses

subnet 192.168.111.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.111.3 192.168.111.50;
}
```